# use javascript variable into python Block

Tags: javascript, jquery, python

I want to use JavaScript variable into python Block.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#WO_cpp_id").change(function() {
   id = this.selectedIndex;
   ajax('{{=URL(r=request,f='get_CIs',vars={'CPP_Id':'#here I want to use id variable')}}', ['WO_cpp_id'], 'WO_ci_id');
})
.change(); }); </script>
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

Your python code is running on the server. Your JavaScript code (as quoted) is running on the client. So you can't directly use a JavaScript variable in your Python code. What you do is *send* the data you want to send from the client to the server in any of several ways.

One of those ways is "ajax". This client-side code will send the contents of the variable `foo` to the server as a "fooParameter" parameter on a POST:

```
var foo = "This is some information";
$.ajax({
    url: "myscript.py",
    method: "POST",
    data: {fooParameter: foo},
    success: function(responseData) {
        // Successful POST; do something with the response if you want
    },
    error: function(jxhr, statusText, err) {
        // Error, handle it
    }
});
```

More in the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and [the Wikipedia article on ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

Answer (score 0):

That won't work. Python runs on the server before the page is ever rendered on the client; Javascript runs in the browser after the page is rendered. The `id` variable isn't even set when the Python code runs.

Instead, you should have your javascript code add the extra data you want to set to an existing query string (or by using the `data` attribute of jQuery's ajax options).